# Very slow network speed (WIFI)

Tags: wireless, internet

I just installed Ubuntu on my desktop. Before this I was using windows and had no trouble downloading or browsing Internet. But right after installing Ubuntu, speed got caped to around 50KBps. Searched a lot of answers on the internet about this problem but none could fix this. Help please!

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c247 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Output of `sudo ishw`

```
<snip> 
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
     product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
     vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
     logical name: enp3s0
     version: c0
     serial: 90:2b:34:28:46:ee
     capacity: 1Gbit/s
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
     configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
     resources: irq:30 memory:fdec0000-fdefffff ioport:df00(size=128) 

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   bus info: usb@1:2
   logical name: wlx10feed259cb5
   serial: 10:fe:ed:25:9c:b5
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=0.29 ip=192.168.0.108 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11`
<snip>
```

Comment: What is your connection speed ? Which DNS do you use ? Did you try using a LAN cable ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Did not get any output for command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` @Pilot6

Comment: @user227495 I didn't try lan. DNS is automatic, and additional  DNS is  2.2.2.2

Comment: Try LAN cable and check

Comment: Then post output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Posted @Pilot6, some additional information is also added (if needed)